# ServiceType was disabled on the node - Why?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Post Deployment, during activation, Service Fabric fails to activate my service with the error "The ServiceType was disabled on the node" [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mh7P.png). What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the service fails to start on a node after several tries, SF will simply disable that type on the node and try to start it up somewhere else. You can see that in your screenshot, before it was disabled, there is an error that says it couldn't start: "There was an error during activation."

Comment: Thanks Vaclav. How do I figure out what was the error during activation? Obviously that error message isn't helping.

Comment: While it's deploying you'll see health errors in your cluster. Depending on the nature of the problem, you might see a stack trace pointing to something in managed code, otherwise you'll see some other info about why the process couldn't start or crashed. Otherwise, you'll have to dig into your own application logs.

Comment: Thank you. We traced in the application log to invalid SSL Thumbprint